# dynamics 365 API 9.1 how to associate opportunity to product

Tags: rest, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

We found that one cannot simply associate an opportunity with a product, as it can be done with opportunity-account or opportunity-contact via setting the field

```
"customerid_contact@odata.bind" : "/contacts({contact_guid})"
```

The MS docs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/opportunityproduct?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9 mention an `opportunityproduct` entity.

Does someone know how this works in detail? Must one create an opportunityproduct entity somehow and map the productid with opportunityid?

Comment: is this solved ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're correct in thinking you need to use the opportunityproduct to associate a Product and an Opportunity together. You can think of this as an N:M relationship where opportunityproduct is the intersect entity although it's not a N:M relationship between the two entities in CRM.

Use the SDK to associate an opportunity to an opportunity product and a product to the opportunity product: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iorganizationservice.associate?view=dynamics-general-ce-9

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of creating Many-to-Many relationships. One is **native** which does not expose the intersect entity and another one is **manual**.

Think like, Native many to many can be created by linking or association of two records, though there’s an internal intersect entity which is storing this can be used in Advanced find queries but there’s no entity form to view the record. So no additional fields.

Whereas, in Manual many to many - the intersect entity is a physical entity (like `opportunityproduct`) storing two related entity lookups (`opportunityid` and `productid`) and also more custom fields can be added to this entity. Form is available for this entity and can be customized.

You can use either `service.Associate()` message or simple `service.Create()` message with two lookup ids to create that intersect entity record.

For web api queries, I recommend you to use [CRM REST builder](https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder) tool for composing and testing the queries.

Sample:

```
var entity = {};
entity["productid@odata.bind"] = "/products(CB14D0FF-82A6-EA11-A812-000D3A32CA3C)";
entity["opportunityid@odata.bind"] = "/opportunities(5B67A6B7-3C5A-EA11-A811-000D3A5A1CAC)";
entity["uomid@odata.bind"] = "/uoms(BF07B35A-8AB2-4CFC-9475-71F8A5FB1D05)";
entity.opportunityproductname = "arun test";
entity.quantity = 5;

Xrm.WebApi.online.createRecord("opportunityproduct", entity).then(
    function success(result) {
        var newEntityId = result.id;
    },
    function(error) {
        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(error.message);
    }
);
```